# IIQ is not opening

Tags: localhost

After I start my Tomcat server on localhost:8080 I try to start my IIQ.

But I am getting below error:

> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found Type Status Report
>
> Message The requested resource [/identityiq] is not available
>
> Description The origin server did not find a current representation
> for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
> Apache Tomcat/8.5.56

What am I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So the IdentityIQ war has not deployed successfully - Generally, that is going to come from a database connection string not being set in the properties file. Another strong possibility is the Tomcat server doesn't have the proper permissions to deploy the current war. If you can post the logs files from Tomcat I would be able to better assist you (generally those logs files can be found at the root of Tomcat). Let me know -